# How to exclude PII data and some Org level words from translation

Tags: nlp, translation, huggingface-transformers, machine-translation

I am building a translation pipeline for my organization using Helsinki-NLP Out Of Box translation models (no fine-tuning involved). I have a requirement where I have to retain certain PII data (like email, mobile number, and geographic data) and a few organization-based glossary words as-is in the translated text.

I understand that the quality of translation might get affected but I am ok with it.

Can someone suggest a way to achieve this with pre-trained models?

Comment: Jörg is usually quick to answer at https://github.com/Helsinki-NLP/Opus-MT/issues.